# prop() hides my button rather than disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I have used prop jQuery syntax to enable my Save button and disable Edit button after Edit button was clicked the moment the event, I don't know why it is non-visible rather than enabling the Save Button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#saveProject').click(function() {
    $('#editProject').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#saveProject').prop("disabled", true);
    $('.fields').prop("disabled", true);
    $('.fields').css({
      "border-bottom": "4px solid teal"
    });
  });

  $('#editProject').click(function() {
    $('#saveProject').prop("disabled", false);
    $('.fields').prop("disabled", false);
    $('.green').css({
      "border-bottom": "4px solid green"
    });
    $('.red').css({
      "border-bottom": "4px solid red"
    });
    $('#editProject').prop("disabled", true);
  });

  $('#clearProject').click(function() {
    $('#clearProject').prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-red">
  <input id="saveProject" type="submit" class="w3-button w3-right w3-col m3" style="background-color:#030066;" value="Save Project" disabled="disabled">
  <input id="editProject" class="w3-button w3-right w3-rightbar w3-col m2" style="background-color:#030066;" value="Edit">
  <input id="clearProject" class="w3-button w3-right w3-rightbar w3-col m4" style="background-color:#030066;" value="Default Values" type="reset">
</div>
```

Comment: You might have a type error `$('#saveProject.visible')` should it not be `$('#saveProject:visible')`

Comment: no, that was not the actual syntax i just experimented that .visible out there and when i tried your way.. still nothing happens

Comment: *"I don't know why it is non-visible rather than enabling the Save Button."* What? 0_0

Comment: try using .attr() instead of .prop :)

Comment: It seems there is no problem in your js. Perhaps your css is hiding the button? https://jsfiddle.net/ajpv11xL/ 
@HanthonyTagam

Comment: ohhhh @SudarpoChong.. thanks for helping man!!

Comment: And your `EDIT` need a `type = "button"` otherwise it will be a textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS fix

```
.w3-button { 
  background-color: #030066;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-button[disabled] {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #888;
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
```

And html

```
<input id="editProject" class="w3-button w3-right w3-rightbar w3-col m2" value="Edit" 
type="button">
```